# display class alert bootstrap in .html javascript

Tags: javascript

```
  $('#info2').html( <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Delete Successful!</strong> 
</div>);
```

i cannot make this work even if i add dobule qoute before and after div content

```
  $('#info2').html( "<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Delete Successful!</strong> 
</div>");
```

Comment: you have to escape the " strings. Try ` '<div class=" ...   ' ` cause you dont need escape

Comment: replace double quoutes with single quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistakes with the quotes. It should be something like this:

```
   $('#info2').html( "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible' role='alert'>
  <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Delete Successful!</strong></div>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have some errors in the console as you are using double quotes to open the function string and double quotes for your property values.

```
$('#info2').html("<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible' role='alert'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button><strong>Delete Successful!</strong></div>");
```

**Note:** Using the console can help with the debugging.

Answer (score 0):

When You have double quotes inside html tags You have to escape the whole string via single quotes

```
$('#info2').html( '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Delete Successful!</strong> 
</div>');
```